# Getting unexpected token error while importing the bootstrap js file

Tags: javascript, eclipse, bootstrap-4

While i downloaded the bootstrap from  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/download/ and imported it to my eclipse and an unexpected error token was seen in the bootstrap.bundle.js , bootstrap.esm.js and bootstrap.js file.

the below is the line of code :

```
_getConfig(config){
config = { ...Default$9, /*error :unexpected token*/
.....config
};
```

Can any one pls help.